# Django - Select shortest game of each type, and its details

Tags: django

So I have a game:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.PROTECT, db_index=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    duration = models.DurationField(null=True, default=None)
    game_type = models.ForeignKey(GameType, models.PROTECT, db_index=True)
    ...

class GameType(models.Model):
    show_name = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True)
    show_photo = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True)
    ...
```

I want to show a leader-board. Which means I need for each GameType, to show the game-type details, the player that won (played the shortest (minimum duration) game), the actual duration, and maybe also the time the game started.

How can this be done efficiently (preferably with a single query) in django?

I thought about something like:

```
GameType.objects.annotate(min_duration=Min("game_set__duration"))
```

But then how do I get the full details of the game, like the `player` and the `start_time` (without issuing more queries of course)?

Another option is:

```
Game.objects.values("game_type").annotate(min_duration=Min("duration"))
```

But again I'm missing all the details of both Game and GameType.

(Django 1.9, MySQL, Python 2.7)

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Aggregate queries only return the value of the distinct column, not an object because there can be multiple games with the same duration.

Comment: You are right. In that case return all of them or the one with the earliest `start_time`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to aggregate the games with the lowest durations. Instead, you just need to `order_by` duration in ascending order so that the smallest durations are first. Finally, slice the queryset based on how many scores you want to display on the leaderboard (below we choose 10).

```
leaderboard_games = Game.objects.all().order_by('duration')[:10]
```

Then in your template just iterate this list:

```
<table>
    {% for game in leaderboard_games %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ game.player }}</td>
            <td>{{ game.duration }}</td>
        <tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to display a single winner (with the shortest game) for each GameType

Comment: You could change the slice from `[:10]` to `[:1]` and the code would still work. You could also just use `[0]` but you'd have to add some code to make sure there was at least one result and you'd have to remove the `{% for %}` loop from the template. Most leaderboards have more than one result so I chose this approach.

Comment: This will get me a single winner and that's it. But I want a single winner per GameType.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

Game.objects.all().annotate(rank=RawSQL("RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY game_type_id ORDER BY -duration DESC)", [])).values('player__username', 'game_type__name', 'duration').distinct('game_type')
```

Learnt from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7606706/2000121

Comment: Assuming that you are using Postgres.

Comment: Thank you. A similar way is `Game.objects.select_related("game_type").order_by("game_type", "duration").distinct("game_type")`. But unfortunately I'm using MySQL (edited the question to mention that).